# How to create a properties file within a folder of workspace

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I need to create new properties file and save values in it. I need to save this properties file inside a package of workspace.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("name", addressForm.getName());
    props.setProperty("address", addressForm.getAddress());
    File f = new File("server.properties");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( f );
    props.store(out, "");
```

This code is not creating any file named server.properties anywhere in the workspace.

Comment: Your Code is works fine refresh the workspace after creating file.

Comment: This code runs fine when i run from an external class with main method. But when i use this in struts, there is no properties file created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may helps you :

```
            Properties propss = new Properties();
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {

                output = new FileOutputStream("server.properties");

                // set the properties value
                  props.setProperty("name", addressForm.getName());
                  props.setProperty("address", addressForm.getAddress());

                // save properties to project root folder
                props.store(output, null);                  

            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (output != null) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: This code is also working when i am running it from a separate main method but is not working when i keep it workspace and access by some other method

Answer (score 0):

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

will give you the root folder of the project.

Example `workingDir`  will give you `E:\workspace\ProjectName`

so try somethinglike this

```
File f = new File(workingDir+ "/server/server.properties");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( f );
```

make sure you have a folder by the name of `server` under the project root